# How to define a summation with function calling itself?

Tags: functions, summation

I am new to Mathematica. I want to do this f(x)=summation f(t), summation is over t, where 1<=t<=x-1 and mod(x+1,t+1)=1, i.e. when x+1 is divided by t+1, remainder is 1 and f(1)=1. Should i use loop or something else and how? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question, you want something like:

```
f[1] = 1;
f[x_] := f[x] = Sum[Boole[Mod[x + 1, t + 1] == 1] f[t], {t, 1, x - 1}]

ListLinePlot[f[#] & /@ Range[1, 100], InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
 PlotRange -> {{1, 100}, All}, AxesOrigin -> {1, 0}]
```

[image]

Note the use of the `:=...=...` construct: this creates "memoization" of results (since the sum will repeatedly use the same values), providing a potentially huge performance boost.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really works...

Comment: @suruchi: Glad to help. That's an interesting function - does it have some special purpose?